# Using Python Tkinter .config() method

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to use the Python Tkinter .config() method to update some message text. I can't get it to work. What might I be doing wrong (see the update_message method):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import alsaaudio as aa
import audioop
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import threading
import Queue

# styles

BACKROUND_COLOR = '#000000'

TYPEFACE = 'Unit-Bold'
FONT_SIZE = 50
TEXT_COLOR = '#777777'

TEXTBOX_WIDTH = 400

# text

TITLE = 'listen closely'
SCORE_MESSAGE = 'your score:\n    '
END_MESSAGE = 'too loud!\ntry again'

# configuration

DEVICE = 'hw:1' # hardware sound card index
CHANNELS = 1
SAMPLE_RATE = 8000 # Hz // 44100
PERIOD = 256 # Frames // 256
FORMAT = aa.PCM_FORMAT_S8 # Sound format

NOISE_THRESHOLD = 3

class Display(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, queue):
        self.parent = parent
        self.queue = queue

        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        parent.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            parent.winfo_screenwidth(), parent.winfo_screenheight()))
        parent.overrideredirect(1)

        parent.title(TITLE)
        parent.configure(background=BACKROUND_COLOR)
        parent.displayFont = tkFont.Font(family=TYPEFACE, size=FONT_SIZE)
        self.process_queue()

    def process_queue(self):
        try:
            score = self.queue.get(0)
            self.print_message(score)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        self.parent.after(100, self.update_queue)

    def update_queue(self):
        try:
            score = self.queue.get(0)
            self.update_message(score)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass

        self.parent.after(100, self.update_queue)

    def print_message(self, messageString):
        print 'message', messageString
        displayString = SCORE_MESSAGE + str(messageString)
        self.message = tk.Message(
            self.parent, text=displayString, bg=BACKROUND_COLOR,
            font=self.parent.displayFont, fg=TEXT_COLOR, width=TEXTBOX_WIDTH, justify="c")
        self.message.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

    def update_message(self, messageString):
        print 'message', messageString
        displayString = SCORE_MESSAGE + str(messageString)
        self.message.config(text=displayString)


def setup_audio(queue, stop_event):
    data_in = aa.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NONBLOCK, 'hw:1')
    data_in.setchannels(2)
    data_in.setrate(44100)
    data_in.setformat(aa.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)

    data_in.setperiodsize(256)

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # Read data from device
        l, data = data_in.read()
        if l:
            # catch frame error
            try:
                max_vol = audioop.rms(data, 2)
                scaled_vol = max_vol // 4680
                print scaled_vol

                if scaled_vol <= 3:
                    # Too quiet, ignore
                    continue

                queue.put(scaled_vol)

            except audioop.error, e:
                if e.message != "not a whole number of frames":
                    raise e


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    queue = Queue.Queue()
    window = Display(root, queue)

    stop_event = threading.Event()
    audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=setup_audio,
                                    args=[queue, stop_event])
    audio_thread.start()
    try:
        root.mainloop()
    finally:
        stop_event.set()
        audio_thread.join()
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't want to be laying down a new message every time I update. If the .config() doesn't work, is there another method to update the text configuration of the message?

Comment: why can't you get it to work? What's preventing that? Are you getting an error? What error?

Comment: I am not getting an error, just a blank screen without text displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I would use string variables, first create your string variable then set it to want you want it to display at the start next make your object and in text put the sting variable then when you want to change the text in the object change the string variable.

```
self.messaget = StringVar()
self.messaget.set("")
self.message = tk.Message(
            self.parent, textvariable=self.messaget, bg=BACKROUND_COLOR,
            font=self.parent.displayFont, fg=TEXT_COLOR, 
            width=TEXTBOX_WIDTH, justify="c").grid()
#note renember to palce the object after you have created it either using 
#.grid(row = , column =) or .pack()
#note that it is textvariable instead of text if you put text instead it will run but
#but will show PY_Var instead of the value of the variable
```

edit
to change the text without recreating the object you do the name of the string variable you have used and .set

```
self.messaget.set("hi")
```

Comment: But, regardless, if I use tk.Message over and over again, I am creating a new widget each time and this is what is causing a screen flicker. I want to use .config() so that I am not creating a new widget each time.

Comment: my answer was probly not clear i included making the message to show that you put textvariable instead of text, what you do when changing the value us the last line which is changing the textvariable